# extends HTTP and call local method (error Symbol(Symbol.iterator)')

Tags: angular, angular-services

## Update:

Hi what I'm trying: `extends Http` service and intercept error status of all my POST request, but I don't understant Why I can't access to my method getTicket() inside my interceptor ?

My HttpService service file:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
    public SERVER_URL: string = 'http://10.0.0.183:8080/alfresco/s/'
    public TICKET: string = ''

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        console.log("ok POST")
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body));
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err) => {

            if (err.status == 401) {
                this.getTicket().map(res => {
                    this.TICKET = res.json().data.ticket
                    return Observable.empty()
                })
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err)
            }

        });
    }

    getTicket() {
        return this.post(this.SERVER_URL + 'api/login', JSON.stringify({
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
        }))
    }

    deleteDocument(idFile: number) {
        return this.post(this.SERVER_URL + 'dms/file/delfile?idfile=' + idFile + '&alf_ticket=' + "jhgjkgjhg", {}).map((data: Response) => data.json())
}
}
```

in my app.module.ts

```
 providers: [CommunicationInsideServices, TicketValidGuard, UserValidGuard, [
        {
            provide: HttpService,
            useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions ) => {
                return new HttpService(backend, options);
            },
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions ]
        }
    ]],
```

Is there a good soul :) to explain me how I can use my local method getTicket() inside interceptor ?!?! cause I get this error:
 Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's actually impossible what you're trying to do (I think).

As you're creating an instance of `HttpCustomService` in your constructor an instance of `HttpService` is created as well.

So when that happens, the constructor of `HttpService` tries to create an instance of `HttpCustomService` as well, but that's impossible. So that's why you're getting the cyclic error.

If you like more info about this subject: [http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modul....](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_cyclic-dependencies)

Comment: thanks, from CustomHttpService how can I call a method inside HttpService ! is there a way?

Comment: As long as `HttpService` doesn't use `CustomHttpService` (or the other way around) there isn't any problem. But I think that is the issue here :-)

Comment: In `ECMAScript 6` this should work, but with `CommonJS` it won't as explained in the article I've posted.

Just search for this title: 16.3.6.2 Cyclic dependencies in ECMAScript 6

Comment: Ok I will update and create only one file HttpService who extends Http

Comment: here you are you can check update... inside one file :)